# Raw socket windows

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I am trying Raw socket programming on windows with winsock. I build a TCP packet and i send it.
The Raw TCP Socket is created and set successfully, I do not receive any errors. The packets are sent correctly, but I cannot see anything using wireshark. If I set the protocol as UDP or other (IGMP etc...) then it works!

Some ideas?

Here the code I am using:

```
    //raw tcp packet crafter

#include "stdio.h"
#include "winsock2.h"
#include "ws2tcpip.h" //IP_HDRINCL is here
#include "conio.h"

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //winsock 2.2 library

typedef struct ip_hdr
{
unsigned char ip_header_len:4; // 4-bit header length (in 32-bit words) normally=5 (Means 20 Bytes may be 24 also)
unsigned char ip_version :4; // 4-bit IPv4 version
unsigned char ip_tos; // IP type of service
unsigned short ip_total_length; // Total length
unsigned short ip_id; // Unique identifier

unsigned char ip_frag_offset :5; // Fragment offset field

unsigned char ip_more_fragment :1;
unsigned char ip_dont_fragment :1;
unsigned char ip_reserved_zero :1;

unsigned char ip_frag_offset1; //fragment offset

unsigned char ip_ttl; // Time to live
//unsigned char ip_proto; // Protocol(TCP,UDP etc)
unsigned char ip_protocol; // Protocol(TCP,UDP etc)
unsigned short ip_checksum; // IP checksum
unsigned int ip_srcaddr; // Source address
unsigned int ip_destaddr; // Source address
} IPV4_HDR, *PIPV4_HDR, FAR * LPIPV4_HDR;

typedef struct tcp_header
{
unsigned short source_port; // source port
unsigned short dest_port; // destination port
unsigned int sequence; // sequence number - 32 bits
unsigned int acknowledge; // acknowledgement number - 32 bits

unsigned char ns :1; //Nonce Sum Flag Added in RFC 3540.
unsigned char reserved_part1:3; //according to rfc
unsigned char data_offset:4; /*The number of 32-bit words in the TCP header.
This indicates where the data begins.
The length of the TCP header is always a multiple
of 32 bits.*/

unsigned char fin :1; //Finish Flag
unsigned char syn :1; //Synchronise Flag
unsigned char rst :1; //Reset Flag
unsigned char psh :1; //Push Flag
unsigned char ack :1; //Acknowledgement Flag
unsigned char urg :1; //Urgent Flag

unsigned char ecn :1; //ECN-Echo Flag
unsigned char cwr :1; //Congestion Window Reduced Flag

////////////////////////////////

unsigned short window; // window
unsigned short checksum; // checksum
unsigned short urgent_pointer; // urgent pointer
} TCP_HDR , *PTCP_HDR , FAR * LPTCP_HDR , TCPHeader , TCP_HEADER;


int main()
{
char host[]="216.58.208.46",buf[1000],*data=NULL,source_ip[]="10.0.2.15"; //buf is the complete packet
SOCKET s;
int k=1;

IPV4_HDR *v4hdr=NULL;
TCP_HDR *tcphdr=NULL;

int payload=0 , optval=1;
SOCKADDR_IN dest;
hostent *server;

//Initialise Winsock
WSADATA wsock;
printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsock) != 0)
{
fprintf(stderr,"WSAStartup() failed");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("Initialised successfully.");
////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Create Raw TCP Packet
printf("\nCreating Raw TCP Socket...");
if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW))==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
printf("Creation of raw socket failed.");
return 0;
}
printf("Raw TCP Socket Created successfully.");
////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Put Socket in RAW Mode.
printf("\nSetting the socket in RAW mode...");
if(setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, (char *)&optval, sizeof(optval))==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
printf("failed to set socket in raw mode.");
return 0;
}
printf("Successful.");
////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Target Hostname
//printf("\nEnter hostname : ");
//gets(host);
printf("\nResolving Hostname...");
if((server=gethostbyname(host))==0)
{
printf("Unable to resolve.");
return 0;
}
dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest.sin_port = htons(80); //your destination port
memcpy(&dest.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);
printf("Resolved.");
/////////////////////////////////////////////////

//printf("\nEnter Source IP : ");
//gets(source_ip);

v4hdr = (IPV4_HDR *)buf; //lets point to the ip header portion
v4hdr->ip_version=4;
v4hdr->ip_header_len=5;
v4hdr->ip_tos = 0;
//v4hdr->ip_total_length = htons ( sizeof(IPV4_HDR) + sizeof(TCP_HDR) + payload );
v4hdr->ip_id = htons(2);
v4hdr->ip_frag_offset = 0;
v4hdr->ip_frag_offset1 = 0;
v4hdr->ip_reserved_zero = 0;
v4hdr->ip_dont_fragment = 0;
v4hdr->ip_more_fragment = 0;
v4hdr->ip_ttl = 8;
v4hdr->ip_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
v4hdr->ip_srcaddr = inet_addr(source_ip);
v4hdr->ip_destaddr = inet_addr(inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
v4hdr->ip_checksum = 0;

tcphdr = (TCP_HDR *)&buf[sizeof(IPV4_HDR)]; //get the pointer to the tcp header in the packet



tcphdr->source_port = htons(49723);
tcphdr->dest_port = htons(80);

tcphdr->cwr=0;
tcphdr->ecn=0;
tcphdr->urg=0;
tcphdr->ack=0;
tcphdr->psh=0;
tcphdr->rst=0;
tcphdr->syn=1;
tcphdr->fin=0;
tcphdr->ns=0;

tcphdr->checksum = 0;


printf("\nSending packet...\n");

for (int i=0; i<=4; i++) 
{
printf(" %d packets send\r",k++);
if((sendto(s , buf , sizeof(IPV4_HDR)+ sizeof(TCP_HDR)+payload, 0,
(SOCKADDR *)&dest, sizeof(dest)))==SOCKET_ERROR)
{

printf("Error sending Packet : %d",WSAGetLastError());
}
i++;
}

return 0;
}
```

To switch to UDP:

```
v4hdr->ip_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP; //(and it works!)
```

Thank's in advance.
Anna

Comment: Are you capturing in Wireshark using a filter or without? Another thing to check is if your firewall is suppressing it silently.

Comment: I think windows does not support sending TCP over raw sockets. See the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548.aspx) chapter _Limitations on Raw Sockets_: _TCP data cannot be sent over raw sockets._

Comment: I am using wireshark without filter. Also Windows Firewall is off.

Comment: I would not send TCP data. I would just send a SYN. Also the compiled code do not have any errors and the socket is created successfully. The packets are also sent. If windows does not support it, I think that an error message should appear when create the socket.

Comment: IMHO raw socket does not check whether there is some data in TCP packet and just discards the packet. MS declares that motivation for limited functionality is avoiding attacks like SYN flood attack and it would not be a good idea to allow faked empty SYN packets. If you read the MSDN attentively then you can find information that the limitation is not applicable for Windows server products. Do you have chance to test the code on a MS Win server?

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Unfortunately I cannot use Windows server :-(      Is there a way to do this using WInpcap?